# Android recyclerview remove all item decorators

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I did this:

```
dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(
        recyclerView.getContext(),
        DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
    );
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

Then i change devices orientation, so now i dont have that dividerItemDecoration, and i want to delete divider from recyclerView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 46):

You could do it like this:

```
while (recyclerView.getItemDecorationCount() > 0) {
    recyclerView.removeItemDecorationAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Good candidate for an extension function!

Answer (score 9):

To delete a ItemDecoration, you need to use **removeItemDecoration**. For your case, the code will be:

```
recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

Comment: what is **dividerItemDecoration** here?

Comment: The divider item decoration is an type of decoration in RecyclerView. It is usually the small line between two items in a RecyclerView. In case, you want to see an [example](http://java-lang-programming.com/public/images/article/19/content/ui-recycler-view-divider-line.png). You can check out more information here: [DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html).

Answer (score 9):

adding to Szymon Chaber answer here is a kotlin extension to make it reusable:

```
fun <T : RecyclerView> T.removeItemDecorations() {
    while (itemDecorationCount > 0) {
        removeItemDecorationAt(0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Kotlin, you can use this extension function used in [Google I/O Android app](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/util/RecyclerViewExtensions.kt)

```
fun RecyclerView.clearDecorations() {
   if (itemDecorationCount > 0) {
     for (i in itemDecorationCount - 1 downTo 0) {
         removeItemDecorationAt(i)
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Kotlin extension function I created to remove all of a recyclerView's item decorations.

```
    /**
     * removes all recyclerview item decorations
     *
     */
    fun RecyclerView.removeItemDecorations() {
        while (this.itemDecorationCount > 0) {
            this.removeItemDecorationAt(0)
        }
    }
```

I use it by calling the following:

```
recyclerView.removeItemDecorations()
```

Don't forget to `import <path to extensions file>._KotlinExtensions.removeItemDecorations`
 at the top of whatever class you plan to use the extension function in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me:

```
RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration;

while (recyclerView.getItemDecorationCount() > 0 
        &&(itemDecoration = recyclerView.getItemDecorationAt(0)) != null) {
                    recyclerView.removeItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
                }
```

Comment: but why is the second condition required? `recyclerView.getItemDecorationAt(0)) != null` . I get an `ArrayOutOfBounds` without it ;/

Comment: actually I'm not sure, I think `getItemDecorationCount` is not reliable enough, sometimes removing item haven't finished yet but `getItemDecorationCount` is called.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in **Kotlin**:

```
var itemDecoration: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration? = null

while (recycler_view.itemDecorationCount > 0 && (recycler_view.getItemDecorationAt(0)?.let { itemDecoration = it }) != null) {
    recycler_view.removeItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
}
```